# Linking Openssl library(calling convention _cdecl) with a dll(calling convention _stdcall)

Tags: c++, windows, dll, openssl, calling-convention

I am including openssl library(openssl.lib) to an dll. When I build this dll, I found few linker errors. I debugged and found that linker errors are because of calling convention of dll. My dll is using _stdcall calling convention whereas openssl is using _cdecl calling convention. I can't change the calling convention of my dll since it is part of existing solution. So I tried to change the calling convention of openssl to _stdcall. But I could not do, it ended up in following build errors.

> > \crypto\ui\ui_openssl.c(591) : error C2440: 'function' : cannot  convert from 'void (__stdcall *)(int)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(int)'
> >     .\crypto\ui\ui_openssl.c(591) : warning C4024: 'signal' : different
> >     types for formal and actual parameter 2 .\crypto\ui\ui_openssl.c(591)
> >     : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl *)(int)' to
> >     'void (__stdcall *)(int)' .\crypto\ui\ui_openssl.c(592) : error C2440:
> >     'function' : cannot convert from 'void (__stdcall *)(int)' to 'void
> >     (__cdecl *)(int)'

Lines of code causing the build errors are:

```
static void pushsig(void)
{ 
#ifndef OPENSSL_SYS_WIN32
   int i;
#endif
#ifdef SIGACTION
 struct sigaction sa;

 memset(&sa,0,sizeof sa);
 sa.sa_handler=recsig;
#endif

#ifdef OPENSSL_SYS_WIN32
 savsig[SIGABRT]=signal(SIGABRT,recsig); // **line 591**
 savsig[SIGFPE]=signal(SIGFPE,recsig);   // **line 592**
 savsig[SIGILL]=signal(SIGILL,recsig);
```

How can I build the openssl library with _stdcall(/Gz) calling convention? Or is there any other solution to this ?

Note : **signal** is a windows API(calling convention is _cdecl). Please refer this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx

Thanks,
Sathish.

Comment: there is no problem mixing code with different calling conventions, what were the original linker errors before you tried changing the calling convention?

Comment: Here are the linker errors observed while linking openssl.lib(_cdecl calling convention) to a dll(_stdcall calling convention).
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _HMAC_CTX_cleanup@4 
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _HMAC_Final@12 
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _HMAC_Update@12 
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _HMAC_Init_ex@20

Answer (score 0):

Changing the default calling convention from the command line is quite an unusual thing to do. I think you have 2 options:

1. Go through the openssl header files and explicitly mark all the functions as `__cdecl`
2. Remove the calling convention command line option and explicitly mark the functions in your project that need to be stdcall with `__stdcall`

Option 2 will cause you far fewer headaches in future when you introduce other third-party libraries into your project. Explicitly marking functions in headers is also going to be more reliable for the consumers of your dll rather than relying on the default calling convention not being set to the usual value of `__cdecl`.